# minimum c++ make file for linux

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation

I've looking to find a simple recommended "minimal" c++ makefile for linux which will use g++ to compile and link a single file and h file. Ideally the make file will not even have the physical file names in it and only have a .cpp to .o transform. What is the best way to generate such a makefile without diving into the horrors of autoconf?

The current dir contains, for example

t.cpp
t.h

and I want a makefile for that to be created. I tried autoconf but its assuming .h is gcc instead of g++. Yes, while not a beginner, I am relearning from years ago best approaches to project manipulation and hence am looking for automated ways to create and maintain makefiles for small projects.

Comment: Make is great for simple projects (and for playing with). But maintaining a big project becomes difficult to do correctly (you can hodge podge it easily but correctly is hard). Use tools 'like scons' to build your make file

Comment: scons looks nice. Certainly easier than Autoconf.

Comment: OMake is great and takes over when make shows its limits.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If it is a single file, you can type

```
make t
```

And it will invoke

```
g++ t.cpp -o t
```

This doesn't even require a Makefile in the directory, although it will get confused if you have a t.cpp and a t.c and a t.java, etc etc.

Also a real Makefile:

```
SOURCES := t.cpp
# Objs are all the sources, with .cpp replaced by .o
OBJS := $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

all: t

# Compile the binary 't' by calling the compiler with cflags, lflags, and any libs (if defined) and the list of objects.
t: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o t $(OBJS) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)

# Get a .o from a .cpp by calling compiler with cflags and includes (if defined)
.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $<
```

Comment: this also doesn't create any dependencies.

Comment: This makefile is almost (but not quite) equivalent to "all : t" and letting the built-in rules take over...

Comment: But why do you have specific rule for t: ? It kind of defeats the point of having a cpp.o rule.

Comment: The t rule generates, from the .o files, the binary by calling the linker. If I had four sources [abcd].cpp and a binary named t, the rule would link all four of those generated objects into one executable.

Comment: You should use `CXX` and `CXXFLAGS` for C++ files, rather than `CC` and `CFLAGS`. Source: [GNU make implicit variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html). Note that `CPPFLAGS` are for the C Pre-Processor, which applies to both C and C++.

Answer (score 19):

Here is a generic makefile from my code snippets directory:

```
SOURCES=$(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
DEPS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.d)
BINS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=)

CFLAGS+=-MMD
CXXFLAGS+=-MMD

all: $(BINS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS) $(DEPS) $(BINS)

-include $(DEPS)
```

As long as you have one .cpp source producing one binary, you don't need anything more. I have only used it with GNU make, and the dependency generation uses gcc syntax (also supported by icc).  If you are using the SUN compilers, you need to change "-MMD" to "-xMMD". Also, ensure that the tab on the start of the line after `clean:` does not get changed to spaces when you paste this code or `make` will give you a missing separator error.

Comment: `all` should be `phony` too .

Comment: Agreed. The GNU Make documentation shows `all` being listed as `.PHONY`. Source: [Phony Targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html)

Answer (score 7):

Have you looked at [SCons](http://www.scons.org/)?

Simply create a SConstruct file with the following:

```
Program("t.cpp")
```

Then type:

```
scons
```

Done!

Comment: Though I love fiddling with makefile (its a language unto itself). I think this is the best answer, but I think you need to expand this answer a bit to explain why using "SCons" is better than using Makefiles directly. I am convinced but there is not enough here to convice others.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming no preconfigured system-wide `make` settings:

```
CXX = g++
CPPFLAGS =        # put pre-processor settings (-I, -D, etc) here
CXXFLAGS = -Wall  # put compiler settings here
LDFLAGS =         # put linker settings here

test: test.o
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) test.o

.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $<

test.cpp: test.h
```

Comment: Again this his a specific line for test. Why?

Comment: because you always have to specify *what* the Makefile will actually build.  With suitable global defs, you might just be able to say just "test:" in the file, but the file above is guaranteed to work regardless of any global rules or macros.

Answer (score 2):

a fairly small GNU Makefile, using predefined rules and auto-deps:

```
CC=c++
CXXFLAGS=-g -Wall -Wextra -MMD
LDLIBS=-lm
program: program.o sub.o
clean:
    $(RM) *.o *.d program
-include $(wildcard *.d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [OMake](http://omake.metaprl.org/manual/omake-doc.html) ?

**OMakeroot**

```
open build/C
DefineCommandVars()
.SUBDIRS: .
```

**OMakefile**

```
.DEFAULT: $(CXXProgram test, test)
```

Then on Linux or Windows, simply type:

```
omake
```

As a bonus, you automatically get:

- parallel builds with the -j option (same as make).
- MD5 checksums instead of timestamps (build becomes resilient to time synchronization failures).
- Automatic and accurate C/C++ header dependencies.
- Accurate inter-directory dependencies (something that recursive make does not offer).
- Portability (1 build chain to rule them all, immune to path style issues).
- A real programming language (better than GNU make).

Comment: If OMake had better support for out-of-source builds and could generate Visual Studio project, it would be very close to perfect.

Comment: We do out-of-source builds with OMake here. There are a few things to know but otherwise it works (0.9.8.5).

Answer (score 0):

Some good references on creating a basic Makefile

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)

http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/

http://www.opussoftware.com/tutorial/TutMakefile.htm

http://www.hsrl.rutgers.edu/ug/make_help.html

The first couple in particular have minimal example Makefiles like you were describing. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

SConstruct with debug option:

```
env = Environment()

if ARGUMENTS.get('debug', 0):
    env.Append(CCFLAGS = ' -g')

env.Program( source = "template.cpp" )
```

Answer (score 0):

florin has a good starting point.  I didn't like gnu autoconf so I started there and took the concept further and called it the MagicMakefile. I have 3 versions of it from simple to more complex. The latest is now on github: https://github.com/jdkoftinoff/magicmake

Basically, it assumes you have a standard layout for the source files of your project and uses the wildcard function to create the makefile rules on the fly which are then eval'd, handling header file dependancies, cross compiling, unit tests, install, and packaging.

[edit] At this point I use cmake for all my projects since it generates useful project files for many build systems.

jeff koftinoff

Comment: Oops! Sorry for the broken links. I moved it to github. https://github.com/jdkoftinoff/magicmake - that being said I use CMake now instead.

Answer (score 0):

I was hunting around for what a minimal Makefile might look like other than

```
some_stuff:
    @echo "Hello World"
```

I know I am late for this party, but I thought I would toss my hat into the ring as well.  The following is my one directory project Makefile I have used for years.  With a little modification it scales to use multiple directories (e.g. src, obj, bin, header, test, etc).  Assumes all headers and source files are in the current directory.  And, have to give the project a name which is used for the output binary name.

```
NAME = my_project

FILES = $(shell basename -a $$(ls *.cpp) | sed 's/\.cpp//g')
SRC = $(patsubst %, %.cpp, $(FILES))
OBJ = $(patsubst %, %.o, $(FILES))
HDR = $(patsubst %, -include %.h, $(FILES))
CXX = g++ -Wall

%.o : %.cpp
        $(CXX) $(HDR) -c -o $@ $<

build: $(OBJ)
        $(CXX) -o $(NAME) $(OBJ)

clean:
        rm -vf $(NAME) $(OBJ)
```

Answer (score -1):

If your issues are because autoconf thinks the .h file is a c file, try renaming it to .hpp or .h++