# Cmake vs make sample codes?

Tags: makefile, cmake

I was wondering if there was any sample code for `Makefile`s (`make`) and `CMakeLists.txt` (`cmake`) that both do the same thing (the only difference being that one is written in `make` and the other in `cmake`).

I tried looking for 'cmake vs make', but I never found any code comparisons. It would be really helpful to understand the differences, even if just for a simple case.

Comment: +1 This is a good question; when I was starting with `cmake` I wanted this too. But I doubt you'll find it because the capabilities just don't map that well one to the other. If you try to make `cmake` act like `make`, you'll drive yourself nuts, seriously. Best just to start from scratch. Things that are trivial in `make` are quite involved in `cmake`, and vice-versa.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill do you have more details on that? So `make` and `cmake` are so distinct that they should be seen more as complementary instead of competing tools?

Comment: @Shurane -- cmake doesn't build anything itself; it creates Makefiles (and other, similar build scripts), which you then run. Therefore whenever you're writing cmake files, you have to think whether a command should apply during generation time, or during build time. Some actions -- copy a wildcarded set of files at build time, for example -- are quite complicated, compared to the "`cp *.x $(OUTDIR)`" you'd write in a Makefile. Perhaps the most annoying part for me is that the generated Makefiles are by design completely nonportable and inflexible (continued)

Comment: (continued) You can't even move the source directory on the same machine without re-running cmake to regenerate the Makefile! So the choice is not between cmake and make, but rather between writing portable Makefiles yourself, or using cmake to generate nonportable ones on each build machine (and given that you can use Cygwin or mingw on Windows, I generally find the former is easier.)

Comment: a nice question, but there is no specific answer, beecause both tools try to solve a different problem. cmake takes information on how to build programs generates makefiles that build the program. Hence cmake is a language with abstract build rules and gnu make is a dependency resolves that executes programs on a directed acyclic graph traversal.

Answer (score 129):

The following Makefile builds an executable named `prog` from the sources
`prog1.c, prog2.c, prog3.c and main.c`. `prog` is linked against `libmystatlib.a`
and `libmydynlib.so` which are both also built from source. Additionally, `prog` uses
the library `libstuff.a` in `stuff/lib` and its header in `stuff/include`. The
Makefile by default builds a release target, but offers also a debug target:

```makefile
#Makefile    
CC = gcc
CPP = g++
RANLIB = ar rcs
RELEASE = -c -O3 
DEBUG = -c -g -D_DEBUG
INCDIR = -I./stuff/include
LIBDIR = -L./stuff/lib -L.
LIBS = -lstuff -lmystatlib -lmydynlib
CFLAGS = $(RELEASE)

PROGOBJS = prog1.o prog2.o prog3.o

prog: main.o $(PROGOBJS) mystatlib mydynlib
    $(CC) main.o $(PROGOBJS) $(LIBDIR) $(LIBS) -o prog 
debug: CFLAGS=$(DEBUG)
debug: prog

mystatlib: mystatlib.o
    $(RANLIB) libmystatlib.a mystatlib.o
mydynlib: mydynlib.o
    $(CPP) -shared mydynlib.o -o libmydynlib.so

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCDIR) $< -o $@ 
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) $(INCDIR) -fPIC  $< -o $@
```

Here is a `CMakeLists.txt`that does (almost) exactly the same, with some comments to underline the
similarities to the Makefile:

```makefile
#CMakeLists.txt     
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)                    # stuff not directly
project(example)                                       # related to building

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/stuff/include) # -I flags for compiler
link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/stuff/lib)        # -L flags for linker

set(PROGSRC prog1.c prog2.c prog3.c)                   # define variable 

add_executable(prog main.c ${PROGSRC})                 # define executable target prog, specify sources
target_link_libraries(prog mystatlib mydynlib stuff)   # -l flags for linking prog target

add_library(mystatlib STATIC mystatlib.c)              # define static library target mystatlib, specify sources

add_library(mydynlib SHARED mydynlib.cpp)              # define shared library target mydynlib, specify sources
#extra flags for linking mydynlib
set_target_properties(mydynlib PROPERTIES POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE TRUE) 
#alternatively:
#set_target_properties(mydynlib PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-fPIC")
```

In this simple example, the most important differences are:

- CMake recognizes which compilers to use for which kind of source. Also, it
  invokes the right sequence of commands for each type of target. Therefore, there
  is no explicit specification of commands like `$(CC) ...`, `$(RANLIB) ...` and so on.
- All usual compiler/linker flags dealing with inclusion of header files, libraries, etc.
  are replaced by platform independent / build system independent commands.
- Debugging flags are included by either setting the variable `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` to "Debug",
  or by passing it to CMake when invoking the program: `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug`.
- CMake offers also the platform independent inclusion of the '-fPIC' flag (via
  the `POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE` property) and many others. Still, more obscure settings can be implemented by hand in CMake just as well as in a Makefile (by using `COMPILE_FLAGS`
  and similar properties). Of course CMake really starts to shine when third party
  libraries (like OpenGL) are included in a portable manner.
- The build process has one step if you use a Makefile, namely typing  `make` at the command line. For CMake, there are two steps: First, you need to setup your build environment (either by typing `cmake <source_dir>` in your build directory or by running some GUI client). This creates a Makefile or something equivalent, depending on the build system of your choice (e.g. make on Unixes or VC++ or MinGW + Msys on Windows). The build system can be passed to CMake as a parameter; however, CMake makes reasonable default choices depending on your system configuration. Second, you perform the actual build in the selected build system.

Sources and build instructions are available at https://github.com/rhoelzel/make_cmake.

Comment: Isn't the Makefile overly complicated? By using `CPPFLAGS` instead of `INCDIR` one could've used the built-in rules and the explicit invocation of the compiler would've been redundant. Similarly for the handling of ar, the built-in rules can cover that as well. Also, why set `CPP` and `CC` explicitly? They're already set to good values by `make`, they're predefined variables. `make` also recognizes which compiler to use for which kind of source, the built-in rules are many.

Comment: And many of these variables should be assigned with `:=` instead of `=`.

Comment: Looking at the description, `cmake` is more comparable to `automake` than `make`.

Comment: The Makefile provided could be reduced to 3/4 lines. You SHOULD specify `INCLUDES` instead of `INCDIR`. You do not need %.o:%.c rules.

Answer (score 8):

Grab some software that uses CMake as its buildsystem (there's plenty of opensource projects to choose from as an example). Get the source code and configure it using CMake. Read resulting makefiles and enjoy.

One thing to keep in mind that those tools don't map one-to-one. The most obvious difference is that CMake scans for dependencies between different files (e.g. C header and source files), whereas make leaves that to the makefile authors.

Answer (score 4):

If this question is about a sample `Makefile` output of the `CMakeList.txt` file then please check the cmake-backend sources and generate one such `Makefile`. If it is not then adding to the reply of @Roberto I am trying to make it simple by hiding the details.

#### CMake function

While `Make` is flexible tool for rules and recipe, `CMake` is a layer of abstraction that also adds the configuration feature.

My plain `CMakeLists.txt` will look like the following,

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(example)
file(GLOB testapp_SOURCES *.cc)
add_executable(testapp ${testapp_SOURCES})
```

Note, that `CMake` hides `how` the build can be done. We only specified `what` is the input and output.

The `CMakeLists.txt` contains list of function-calls that are defined by `cmake`.

#### (CMake function) Vs Make rules

In `Makefile` the `rules and recipes` are used instead of `functions` . In addition to `function`-like feature, `rules and recipes` provide chaining. My minimalistic `Makefile` will look like the following,

```
-include "executable.mk"
TARGETS=testapp.bin
all:${TARGETS}
```

While the `executable.mk` will look like the following,

```
SOURCES=$(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
DEPS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.d)

%.bin:$(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.PHONY: all clean

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS) $(DEPS) $(TARGETS)

-include $(DEPS)
```

Starting from the scratch I shall start with a `Makefile` like the following,

```
all: testapp.bin

testapp.bin:sourcea.o sourcb.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.PHONY: all clean

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS) testapp.bin
```

I got this snippet from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287259/minimum-c-make-file-for-linux) and modified it. Note that some implicit-rules are added to this file which can be found in the makefile-documentation. Some implicit variables are also relevant here.

Note, that `Makefile` provides the detail `recipe` showing `how` the build can be done. It is possible to write `executable.mk` to keep the details defined in one file. In that way the makefile can be reduced as I showed earlier.

#### Internal Variables in `CMake` and `Make`

Now getting little advanced, in `CMake` we can set a compiler flag like the following,

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-Wall")
```

Please find out more about `CMake` default variables in `CMakeCache.txt` file.
The `CMake` code above will be equivalent to `Make` code below,

```
CFLAGS = -Wall
```

Note that `CFLAGS` is an internal variable in `Make`, the same way, `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` is internal variable in `CMake` .

#### adding include and library path in CMake

We can do it in `cmake` using functions.

```
target_include_directories(testapp PRIVATE "myincludes")
list(APPEND testapp_LIBRARIES
    mytest mylibrarypath
)
target_link_libraries(testapp ${testapp_LIBRARIES})
```

#### Vs adding include and library path in Make

We can add include and libraries by adding lines like the following,

```
INCLUDES += -Imyincludes
LIBS += -Lmylibrarypath -lmytest
```

Note this lines above can be generated from auto-gen tools or pkg-config. (though Makefile is not dependent of auto-config tools)

#### CMake configure/tweek

Normally it is possible to generate some `config.h` file just like `auto-config` tools by using `configure_file` function. It is possible to do more trick writing custom functions. And finally we can select a config like the following,

```
cmake --build . --config "Release"
```

It is possible to add some configurable option using the `option` function.

#### Makefile configure/tweak

If somehow we need to compile it with some debug flag, we can invoke the `make` like,

```
make CXXFLAGS=NDEBUG
```

I think internal variables, `Makefile-rules` and `CMake-functions` are good start for the comparison, good luck with more digging.