# cmake equivalent for MakeFile

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19266355/4014487) answer to create a CMakeLists.txt for a simple Makefile

**Makefile**

```
CC = g++
INCFLAGS = -I/usr/local/include/embree3
LDFLAGS = -L"/usr/local/lib/" -lembree3
RM  = /bin/rm -f

all:
    $(CC) -o main main.cpp $(INCFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)
clean:
    $(RM) *.o main
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0)
project(some_project)

include_directories(/usr/local/include/embree3) # -I flags for compiler
link_directories(/usr/local/lib/) # -L flags for linker

add_executable(main main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(main embree)   # -l flags for linking prog target
```

The Makefile compiles properly and the executable runs without any issues. And to use the cmake file, I do the following (assuming I am in source directory)

1. mkdir build
2. cd build
3. cmake ..
4. make

The `make` in step 4 throws the following error

```
main.cpp:4:10: fatal error: 'embree3/rtcore.h' file not found
#include <embree3/rtcore.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: include_directories(/usr/local/include/embree3) would point within the embree3 directory. Is there a second nested embree3 directory in there ?

Comment: Maybe try include_directories(/usr/local/include) in your CMakeLists.txt ?

Comment: @LaurentJospin thanks a lot! it works after making that change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so following your answer to my comments, the problem is that since you starts your include instruction by embree3 (which make sense to avoid names conflict), cmake should have as include directory the directory containing the  embree3 installation, not the embree3 folder itself.

This is why include_directories(/usr/local/include) is working instead of include_directories(/usr/local/include/embree3).