# Need help understanding makefile pattern rule % : %.o

Tags: c++, makefile

I want to change this makefile into something simpler using pattern rules I read about in a book:

```
VPATH = src
CPPFLAGS = -I include

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ $(CPPFLAGS) $<
TwoDimensionalShape.o: TwoDimensionalShape.cpp
    g++ -c $(CPPFLAGS) $<
Square.o: Square.cpp Square.h
    g++ -c $(CPPFLAGS) $<
Circle.o: Circle.cpp Circle.h
    g++ -c $(CPPFLAGS) $<
Rectangle.o: Rectangle.cpp Rectangle.h
    g++ -c $(CPPFLAGS) $<
Triangle.o: Triangle.cpp Triangle.h
    g++ -c $(CPPFLAGS) $<
ShapeStack.o: ShapeStack.cpp ShapeStack.h
    g++ -c $(CPPFLAGS) $<
ScreenManager.o: ScreenManager.cpp ScreenManager.h
    g++ -c $(CPPFLAGS) $<
ScreenState.o: ScreenState.cpp ScreenState.h
    g++ -c $(CPPFLAGS) $<
SquareState.o: SquareState.cpp SquareState.h
    g++ -c $(CPPFLAGS) $<
CircleState.o: CircleState.cpp CircleState.h
    g++ -c $(CPPFLAGS) $<
```

After reading the book I can write the above using pattern rules like this. But I don't understand how it is working:

```
#source files are in "src" folder.
VPATH = src
#header files are in "include" folder.
CPPFLAGS = -I include -Wall

all: main.o TwoDimensionalShape.o Square.o Circle.o Rectangle.o Triangle.o ShapeStack.o ScreenManager.o ScreenState.o SquareState.o CircleState.o
    g++ $(CPPFLAGS) $^

%.o: %.cpp
    g++ -c $(CPPFLAGS) $<

%: %.o
    g++ $<
```

This makefile is correct however I don't understand how it is working.

1. If I change for example 2 source files, how does this makefile understand to only compile the changed two source files and not all of source files?
2. In the book I read, example was about C not C++ and last line was `%: %.c`. Then why is my line which is `%: %.o` working? Shouldn't it be `%: %.cpp`?

Comment: Work backwards. Look at your _all_ rule, that will be inspected first. Next, make needs to figure out whether each of the listed `.o` dependencies are up-to-date, so it looks for a rule matching them, which is always the `%.o: %.cpp` rule. So it looks at `main.cpp` to figure out if `main.o` is up-to-date, and the same for each of the others

Comment: Oh, and run it with `-d` to debug your makefile, this will show what rules it considers for each file

Comment: @jamek - `make` _is_ cross-platform. Changing to cmake just changes which tool you're asking about, it doesn't solve anything.

Comment: @Useless Why did you post this only as a comment and not as an answer?

Comment: @jamek: You are wrong, because cmake is not a replacement for make, it is a replacement for autotools! cmake itself generates makefiles e.g. for gnu make. So it is a totally different approach! And for that make is already multi plattform, because it runs also on windows and others. If OP wants to automatically create makefiles, he can take a look for cmake, autotools and some more tools around that!

Comment: You can use Make's built-in `%.o: %.cpp` rule if you correctly set `CXX` and `CXXFLAGS`.  And you can set `LINK.o = $(LINK.cc)` to use the built-in linker rule.  Slim makefiles are better makefiles!

Comment: @Jerome - advice on *how to obtain an answer* is a comment.  Only actual answers should be posted as Answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This makefile is correct however I don't understand how it is working.

If your new Makefile is a replacement for the old one, it is definitely NOT working.

In the "old" one you have e.g.

```
ShapeStack.o: ShapeStack.cpp ShapeStack.h
```

which tells that ShapeStack.o depends on the .cpp and header file. Your new Makefile did not have any dependencies to other files which will result in a lot of trouble. Simply touch one of your headers and type make. Nothing will happen!

So at minimum you have to introduce your source file dependecies, maybe manual as in your old makefile or with some more automatism which uses the dependency check from the compiler, using gcc it is with "gcc -MM".

For getting automated prerequisites see  https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Prerequisites.html

And using vpath can result in a lot of trouble. There are some articels, e.g.:
http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/how-not-to-use-vpath/

Some example Makefiles can be found already here:
[minimum c++ make file for linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287259/minimum-c-make-file-for-linux?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Thank you very much.I used `g++ -MM` but gave me lots of warnings... I have to read the link you provided, also manually introducing header files will result in the same wall of text as first makefile ...

Comment: @mhm: For small projects writing all the rules for automatic generating deps is more then handcrafted rules. But you should think to write *once* a universal Makefile which have this feature and use it in all your projects. And every new project only needs one line of code: OBJS=a.o, b.o... and a include for the generic one. Manual writing the deps is error prone and should not be done at all!

Comment: @mhm: added a resource to find simply Makefiles with autodep generation. Attention: The accepted answer is NOT correct!

Comment: The advice is against using `VPATH` *wrongly*.  It looks like it's used well here.

Comment: @TobySpeight: It is mentioned here as it is often used wrongly. I did not said that it is used wrongly *here*.