# Static pattern rule for makefile

Tags: makefile

I have to make a static pattern rule in this makefile to avoid to use all the source files for each executable file.

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall
LDFLAGS =
OBJFILES = structuri_c.o structuri_1.o structuri_2.o structuri_3.o structuri_4.o 
TARGET = structuri_c structuri_1 structuri_2 structuri_3 structuri_4

all: $(TARGET)
$(TARGET): $(OBJFILES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJFILES) $(LDFLAGS)
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJFILES)
```

Can you help me to do this and to understand why i should do this ?

In this part :

```
TARGET = structuri_c structuri_1 structuri_2 structuri_3 structuri_4

all: $(TARGET)
$(TARGET): $(OBJFILES)
```

I have to make that static pattern rule

Comment: You are saying all the targets depend on all the object files. You want a simple pattern rule instead. It should not be hard to find examples.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need help understanding makefile pattern rule % : %.o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50018305/need-help-understanding-makefile-pattern-rule-o)

Comment: It looks like you want to build each of several executable files from (only) a correspondingly-named `.c` source file, using a compiler specified by variable `CC`, C compiler flags specified in `CFLAGS`, and linker flags specified in `LDFLAGS`.  In that case, have you considered simply relying on `make`'s *built-in* rules?  You would do that by removing the rule for `$(TARGETS)` altogether, without replacement, but keeping the rest.

Comment: Why your current makefile is wrong: your present rule for `$(TARGETS)` says that *each* specified target depends on *all* the object files, and its recipe in fact does attempt to link all of the objects to form each target.  That's at least consistent, but neither of those properties is what you want.

Comment: Note also that you seem already to be depending on `make`'s built-in rule for building object files from C source files, so I guess you're ok with using the built-in rules in general.

Comment: Oke, now after i make the file i have some errors 
"gcc -Wall    structuri_c.c   -o structuri_c
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccXYtUI6.o: in function `main':
structuri_c.c:(.text+0x6a): undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: structuri_c] Error 1
"

Comment: First, just to be clear you have not used a static pattern rule: a static pattern rule will contain a pattern character (`%`).  If you HAD created a static pattern rule it would have worked, but a normal pattern rule works as well.  https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html

Comment: Second, your link issue is a completely different problem and you should file a new question, not tack on comments to an existing question.  But, this is one of the more common problems so please try to search for the answer BEFORE asking a new question.  SO is only for use after your attempts to solve problems on your own have failed: it's a last resort not a first (or second) resort.